# HTML email issue on forwarding

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, outlook-2016

I am wanting to forward an HTML email I had created so that the users can edit some text and forward themselves in Outlook.  However when I forward it, I am getting some space added by Outlook when its being forwarded.

Iin the image attached, the side with the gray background (marked 2) is the gap I am talking about. The other part of the image (marked 1) is the original HTML received.

I had a look at the other newsletters I receive from companies and a couple have this issue too when I forward it. But some do not but I cannot work out why.

Many thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: I forgot to add that it seems to be doing it at the bottom of each table in sections (not html section) that I have of the newsletter. But not at the top (well I think not at the top)

Comment: I had a look at the Source Code in Outlook and it seems Outlook is adding this code (for some reason) to my html:

<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

The >> <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p> << is the issue though. Why is it inserting blank spaces between my tables for?

Answer (score 1):

In generel, all forwarding of html email will destroy our code because it uses Word rendering engine. Outlook will add a ton of styles/spaces/tags you can't control. 
When forwarding a mail in Outlook, make sure to sent it as an attachment, then the styles will be intact.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

However some emails that I do forward on that are HTML do not have that issue. Would if be because it may of been made in Word instead?

Comment: After a days worth of looking at it, I have worked out that Outlook (or whatever renderer it is); is wanting to add o:p code for the way certain tables are nested.

So instead of creating another table below my sections, I created a table row and then nested the table/s in that. It seems to not insert that code when I do it that way.

Comment: Thats a very odd behavior. But great you found some answers